# ng-file-upload gives error message twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

File upload api : [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)

**Html**

```
 <button ngf-select="vm.addPictures($files)" ngf-multiple="true" ngf-pattern="'.jpg,.png,.jpeg,.bmp'"
                            accept="image/*">
                        Select Files
                    </button>
```

**Js**

```
       //to add Pictures
       vm.addPictures = function ($files) {
              vm.upload = [];
              if ($files && $files.length) {
              //$files: an array of files selected, each file has name, size, and type
                  for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
                          var $file = $files[i];
                            (function (index) {
                              vm.upload[index] = upload.upload({
                                 url: "/api/Picture/AddPictures",
                                 method: "POST",
                                 data: {},
                                        file: $file
                                    }).progress(function () {
                                    }).success(function (data) {
                                        vm.pictureList.push({
                                            id: vm.pictureList.length + 1,
                                            url: '/common/pictures/' + data.newImageName,
                                            note: '',
                                            isSelected: true,
                                        });

                                    }).error(function () {
                                    });
                                })(i);
                            }
                 } else {
  abp.message.error('Invalid file format', 'Error');//this is the error msg which it fires twice.
                 }
              };
```

**Question :**  When user selects the wrong format it gives the error message as expected.But after that when user tries to select the image again by just pressing the "Select" button,It shows the same error message again even without selecting the image.Could you tell me how to fix this ? Thanks.

**UPDATE :** When I select a wrong file type,it looks like this...

[image]

Comment: After message, remove that file from $files

Comment: @ShailendraSinghDeol Sorry,I couldn't get what you said.Can I have a code snippet for that ? Thanks.

Comment: Does this go inside if condition if length is 0?

Comment: @ShailendraSinghDeol No,It goes to the `else` part (i.e. shows the error message).Thanks.

Comment: Actually, , i was seeing https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload , in which they have documented that 'ngf-select' will call when images are select or cleared.I think, when user goes to select second time, it clear old files and call this method again. i think that why this issue occurs,

Comment: @ShailendraSinghDeol Do you know how to fix that ? Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105378/discussion-between-shailendra-singh-deol-and-sampath).

Comment: Shallendra is right. If you wanna detect the invalid files either use the angular form validations like the first jsfiddle sample in the docs or use 'ngf-invalid-model' directive to detect invalid files being selected.

Comment: @danial Can you give me an example of how to handle `ngf-model-invalid` with the multiple File select ? I cannot use Angular form with the submit button.Thanks.
Please update the below mentioned fiddle and let me know the new url.http://jsfiddle.net/sampath_lokuge/2vq88rfs/472/